# Merge two vector files and their attribute tables into one file in QGIS

Tags: file, merge, qgis

I'm working with vector files containing burnt areas (BA) and the attribute table lists each BA with the start date of the fire, end date, area affected, etc. I have BA files for the year 2018 and have extracted the entire month of August but now I want to add two more BAs from July that I have extracted separately from the original file. The attribute tables are therefore identical in "shape" (same columns). So in short, I want to add the two vector files together so that my August file has the two BAs for July as rows 1 and 2.

I'm asking this question here because the options that my internet search has given me have not worked (such as Join, Vector -> Data Management -> Merge Vector Layers, Union, etc.). I get the error message: "." files are not supported as outputs for this algorithm" for the options listed above. Any ideas on how to add the files together?I am new to QGIS and have no other ideas on what to try and the already asked Qs on here did not help. Please help.

Comment: Please add exactly what you did to merge them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error is usually caused by an ordinary problem. If the input and output file names contains space or special character, remove them and also for output file, use save to file option as in the photo below.

[image: save to file]

Comment: Dear zekican demiralay, thank you for your help. The layer name did indeed contain spaces because it was an extract of another layer and was saved by QGIS as: ardida_S3A_20190803_2340 — extract__ardida_2019_08__ardida_2019 and by deleting everying after 2340 the data management > merge vector files tool worked just fine. Thanks again and I wish you a good day!